# jQuery circular animation based on right and left controls and friction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is a rather biggish question that i am just hoping to find some direction with.. I dont expect anyone to do this entire thing... But to rather learn how to go about projects like this. Here we go:

I am trying to achieve an this animation:

[image]

Basically whats happening here is, I need to have a semi oval shape and a ball constrained to it and when you press the left and right arrows it needs to slowly to quickly move left to right and based on the speed of the button clicks it needs to either complete the ramp or stop and drop. Imagine a skateboard and a ramp.

I know the basics of jQuery but the circular animation and friction effect is where i get lost..

Any Help/Direction/Advice Greatly Appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you may need something like [box2d-js](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html)

Comment: You're for sure going to need a physics engine for this. I'm curious as to how you plan for the ball to go along the top arc. Could you give more information? I would think if it went off of one of the sides it'd go straight up and then fall down, not go in that arc you show

Comment: Well, physics engine is a bit hardcore isn't it? i mean this doesn't have to be 100% accurate, just similar.... For the arc i was thinking of this plugin: http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/07/20/animating-with-curves-in-jquery/ and just kind of hiding the top section of the line... but not to sure yet...

Comment: you can create a path extending jquery animate like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYgEB/)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2F7D/) with Tween and curve

Comment: WOW!, Thanks this is a great starting point

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying an answer for the animation part: 
If you are ok with HTML5 then for the animations there are two ways to go:

Either use HTML5 Canvas, which really works well for providing dynamic content. Its basically a canvas on which you can freely draw. It's pixel based and has a good performance and, if done right it does not decline very much when drawing many elements). You should also double-buffer it in order to avoid any flickering when drawing.

Or use HTML5 Inline Svg. It's vector based, so resolution-independent and has good support for animating svg elements. In contrast to HTML5 Canvas the elements of the svg are DOM-Nodes, so you see the graphic elements directly in your DOM-Tree.

```
In order to sum up the trade-offs:
HTML5 Canvas
-Pixel-based
-Good Performance
-Free drawing
HTML5 Inline Svg
-Vector-based
-Animations built-in
-Elements are DOM-Nodes
```

For much more information, see 
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/svg-or-canvas-choosing-between-the-two/